# To combine ArrayList and an Array to form a resultant Array of some pattern

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of integer type and an Array of string type. I would like to form an resultant array which is a combination of both. Constraint is that I'm not allowed to use any map interface.

**Example :**

```
ArrayList<Integer> al=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
String name[]={"Cat","bat","mat"} 
//my resultant array should look like this
//String result[]=[cat[1,2,3],bat[4,5,6],mat[7,8,9]]
```

Kindly, suggest me efficient ways to achieve this.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that result should be a String array and not some better fitting data structure? For example a `List<String, List<Integer>>` seems to make a lot more sense.

Comment: Look about [Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html). What you need is a Map<String, List<Integer>>.

Comment: I get it. But for further manipulation purpose i need to have it in the form of an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the result is of type String, you can use [**`List::subList`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) to get a range from your list for example :

```
List<Integer> al = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
String[] names = {"Cat", "bat", "mat"};
String[] result = new String[names.length];
int j = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    result[i] = names[i] + al.subList(j - 3, j);
    j += 3;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(result));
```

Ouputs

```
[Cat[1, 2, 3], bat[4, 5, 6], mat[7, 8, 9]]
```

---

**Note**

You have to check the lengths before you use your array and list or you can get an error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`  Exception

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem in following manner.
Create en entry class having (String name, int [] number) as its members.
Then based on the logic populate the objects of this class to generate

```
name: cat, int [] number= 1,2,3.
```

The outer array would be collection of these Entry objects.

Entry class would be

```
class Entry{
String name;
int[] numbers;
Entry(String name, int[] numbers){
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the size of the list by length of an array, get the threshold and use it to store the results into the `Map`, e.g.:

```
List<Integer> al= Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
String name[]= new String[]{"Cat","bat","mat"};

int elementsPerNode = al.size() / name.length;

Map<String, List<Integer>> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(String element : name) {
    resultMap.put(element, new ArrayList<Integer>());
}

for(int i=0 ; i < al.size() ; i++) {
    resultMap.get(name[i / elementsPerNode]).add(al.get(i));
}

System.out.println(resultMap);
```